# WebPack@5.38.1 with Babel-loader@8.2.2 error while building a react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am trying to set my development environment to start a project. at this point, I added **webpack.config.dev.js** file with some dependencies. Also, added **babel-confing** to the package.json directly instead of **.babelrc** file. I tried adding a couple of dependencies such as: "@babel/preset-env" and "@babel/preset-react" but didn't help. I appreciate it if anyone can help me understand how to fix this?

I am getting the below error while starting the webpack:

```
> start
> webpack serve --mode development --env development --hot --port 3000

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /a/b/c/d/e/f/03/demos/<project-name>
✖ ｢wdm｣: asset main.js 408 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 25.9 KiB 10 modules
cacheable modules 339 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ 21.2 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 20.9 KiB 10 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ 296 bytes 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/url/ 41.9 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/url/node_modules/ 18.8 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/url/*.js 23.1 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 61 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 4.3 KiB 4 modules
  5 modules
./node_modules/webpack/hot/ sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| function Hi() {
>   return <p>Hi.</p>;
| }
| 

webpack 5.38.1 compiled with 1 error in 433 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ps-redux",
  "description": "React and Redux Pluralsight course by Cory House",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --env development --hot --port 3000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "5.0.1",
    "immer": "9.0.3",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.14.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.7",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "0.6.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "10.0.0",
    "css-loader": "5.2.6",
    "cssnano": "5.0.5",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "eslint": "7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.4",
    "fetch-mock": "9.11.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.1",
    "http-server": "0.12.3",
    "jest": "27.0.4",
    "json-server": "0.16.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "postcss-loader": "5.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.1.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.4.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8"
  },
  "babel-cli": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also attached my project folder structure

and this is my webpack.config.dev.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";

module.export = {
  mode: "development",
  target: "web",
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  entry: "./src/index",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    stats: "minimal",
    overlay: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    https: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      favicon: "./src/favicon.ico",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: ["babel-loader", "eslint-webpack-plugin"],
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
  },
};
```

My folder structure img:

Comment: I only use `use: ["babel-loader"]` and my entry looks like: `entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js']` those are really the two biggest things I see at first glance. I would need to do more testing to try and pinpoint the issue tho.

Comment: Thank you. Also, looks like 'babel-polyfill' has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of required parts of core-js and regenerator-runtime. Should I still use that since I am using the new version of Babel?

Comment: Yes. If you are using a newer version of webpacck 7.4.0 or higher then you should use the replacement package.

Comment: I added `entry: ["core-js", "./src/index"],` and `use: ["babel-loader"]` and `import "core-js"` to the index.js file , but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue plz?